# MySQL SELECT statement to select N rows from products WHERE AVERAGE price is X

Tags: mysql, sql, grouping, average

Can't come up with a query that would allow me to select N number of products from one table with average price of X amount and limit to Y number of rows.

IE. select 1000 products where average price is 90.00

```
SELECT * 
FROM ProductList 
WHERE Price = [something something something based on AVG price LIMIT 1000]
```

table with products is not big, so having multiple subselects or functions or stored procedures is not an issue

can even create a new table that will have product ids to join on for selects

Comment: Is your "average price" an average of prices for all products?  Or do products have multiple prices?  If the former, are you looking for products that have the exact average (mean) price, or in some "range" around it?

Comment: an actual average of all products to select, 1000 products where average price is 90.00 should select 1000 products with the average amongst all selected entries to add up to 90.00 on average

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
select
*
from
ProductList
where price = (select avg(price) from productlist)
```

Comment: this would do a lookup for average price and try to select a product where the price is equal to average price, additionally - this query doesn't take into account both variables of either N number of items or X average price